# How to find $R$? Griffith's Electrodynamics problem 1.9 (rotation through (1,1,1))

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, vectors, rotation

> Find the transformation matrix $R$ that describes a rotation by 120◦
> about an axis from the origin through the point (1, 1, 1). The rotation is clockwise
> as you look down the axis toward the origin

I had found similar question in [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485695/) already. But that doesn't answer my question, So I am going to write new one.

In Griffiths EM I found that $\bar A_i = \sum_{j,k}(\sum_{i}R_{ij}R_{ik})A_jA_k =\sum_j \bar R_{ij}\bar A_j$

I wonder how can I find R from the equation. From tensor, I wrote

$$\begin{pmatrix}R_{xx} & R_{xy} & R_{xz} \\ R_{yx} & R_{yy} & R_{yz} \\ R_{zx} & R_{zy} & R_{zz}\end{pmatrix}=R$$
So I wrote
$$\begin{pmatrix}\bar A_x \\ \bar A_y \\ \bar A_z\end{pmatrix}=R\begin{pmatrix} A_x \\  A_y \\  A_z\end{pmatrix}$$

I was thinking that how can I find R from the equation either. At first, I was thinking to sent right basis vectors to left so they will be tranpose matrix. From my study of matrix, I remember we don't deal with equation like that.

So how can I find $R$?

Comment: A hint (why they said what they did), you're looking for a rotation matrix that rotates $z\to y$, $y \to x$, and $x \to z$. in that order.

Comment: Duplicate : [Rotation of a vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252942/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotation of a vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252942/r)